# Best Practices consuming a Soap request over SSL

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap

Just have a quick a question regarding best practices.

I am connecting to a 3rd party api via soap over HTTPS.

To do this I have simply added a service reference to my application by entering the 3rd party wsdl address.

In my C# application I have simply instantiated the service passed in my api key and can successfully retrieve data.

I am aware that this would of failed if the servers ssl certificate didn't meet the following requirements.

- the URL in the certificate matches the URL I'm posting to
- the certificate is valid and trusted
- the certificate has not expired

However, is this secure enough? Is it possible for the ssl certificate to be hijacked or faked? Do I need to store a copy of the valid certificate locally and check the server certificate against the local copy?

Thanks

Ant

Comment: This is a broad question. If you can not narrow it, the broad answer is here: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-52r1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @FerdinandSwaters I suppose my question was really is there any real need to download the certificate locally as a best practice, or is simply checking: the URL in the certificate matches the URL I'm posting to, the certificate is valid and trusted and he certificate has not expired sufficient